# Mathematical derivation of why Bagging reduces variance

Tags: regression, machine-learning, variance, expected-value

I am having a problem understanding the following math in derivation that bagging reduces variance. The math is shown but can not work it out as some steps is missing. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Jge.png)

Comment: Which steps do you want help with?

Comment: "the errors are unbiased and uncorrelated" part until the end. Also why here the MSE not sqaured when using the a(x) unlike when using b(x)

Comment: Can you provide the full source to your question?